# Onclick link submit form using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a close icon on a link. When i click on that icon , it should submit the form .Please help.I am new to jquery ajax.

```
<div class="main1 name-show">
<div id="nameRemove">
<form action="<?php echo site_url('info/removename'); ?>" method="post"  id="ajaxname">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="dwfrm_cart_couponCode">
        Name</label>

              <?php if(!empty($arr_name)){
                        echo $arr_name['name'];
                    }
              ?>
        <a href="#" class="remove_name">

              <img src="<?=base_url()?>images/close-icon.png" id="remove_btn">
         </a>
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=(!empty($arr_name))? $arr_name['id'] :''?>">
         <input type="hidden" class="name-code" name="pr_name" id="dwfrm_cart_couponCode"  value="<?=(!empty($arr_name))? $arr_name['name']:''?>">
        <div class="confirm-name"></div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: use `$('#remove_btn').click(function(){ $('#ajaxname').submit();})`

Comment: Change your `<a>` to `<button type='submit'>..img..</button>`

Comment: Also, there's no "ajax" here and no need for jquery either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve you problem.

**First**: Involves modification to you html. Change you anchor tag to button with type="submit"

```
<div class="main1 name-show">
<div id="nameRemove">
<form action="<?php echo site_url('info/removename'); ?>" method="post"  id="ajaxname">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="dwfrm_cart_couponCode">
        Name</label>

              <?php if(!empty($arr_name)){
                        echo $arr_name['name'];
                    }
              ?>
        <button type="submit" class="remove_name">

              <img src="<?=base_url()?>images/close-icon.png" id="remove_btn">
         </button>
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=(!empty($arr_name))? $arr_name['id'] :''?>">
         <input type="hidden" class="name-code" name="pr_name" id="dwfrm_cart_couponCode"  value="<?=(!empty($arr_name))? $arr_name['name']:''?>">
        <div class="confirm-name"></div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

**Second:** Include jquery to trgger form submit of link click.

```
$('#remove_btn').click(function(){ 
   $('#ajaxname').submit();
});
```